# Why isn't my ground plane in Kicad connecting all of my grounds?

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design

I'm building a low noise power supply and when I try to pour the ground plane, some of my grounds are still unconnected. I tried redoing the board this morning, but I'm still having the same problem. [image]
[image]

I've attached both the schematic and the PCB. Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you!

UPDATE:
I changed the position of C1 and added an exposed GND pin to the schematic but that's also not connecting to the ground plane. Are there settings on it that I need to change to have them connect?
[image]

Comment: This may be the wrong thing, so I won't make an answer of it.  I usually route all of the grounds, then do the pour.  That way I am sure to get all of the grounds.  And if I can't route a ground connection, the pour wouldn't get in, either.  There ought to be a way to make Kicad see the ground plane as connecting the grounds, but I haven't found it.  Haven't really looked, either.

Comment: Connect PIN 13 to ground..., its omitted from your schematic.

Comment: Where is PIN 13?

Comment: Pin 13 is the ground pad beneath the chip

Comment: I added a pin 13 on the schematic and tied it to GND, and then updated the PCb but nothing changed. Do I need to start my PCB from scratch?

Comment: Edit the schematic symbol of U1 to have an extra pin. Make sure you also edit your PCB footprint to incorporate that pin somewhere (as a pad) beneath the chip in the middle. You might then need to re-import the modified footprint and then copy that footprint to U1's position. If it were PADs software I'd import the new part (unconnected as U100) and have it there on the side somewhere then tell U1 to copy U100's footprint. I don't know how kicad will do this but it will I'm sure.

Comment: Or you could manually add a net from the copper already underneath U1 and connect it manually to ground.

Comment: You have another problem.  Pin 11 should be tied to pin 12.  Both are output from the chip.  Neither should go to ground.

Comment: @JRE You're doing it wrong.  Kicad automatically includes all of the ground connected rat runs when you pick that net for the pour. Similarly for any other net like a power one.  You just have to keep repeating it if you move the parts about.

Answer (score 7):

The LT3045 requires that the pad beneath it be grounded so add this as a pin to your circuit and show it connecting to ground. Then pins 9 and 11 can be routed to the pad beneath the chip and make a ground connection easily: -

[image]

You should also re-position C1 to make its 0 V connection much stronger and less disruptive (I also believe this should be close to the chip and not strung out where it is). If you were prepared to route tracks under R2 then you wouldn't need the single track on the other layer. Better still, make that other layer a full ground plane.

Comment: Do I add the pin on the footprint?

Comment: @Bex.1233, Add it to schematic symbol. It's already on the footprint.

Comment: Sorry, how can I add it to my schematic?

Comment: @Andy aka, I added the changes that you had suggested but the gnd pins still aren't all connecting. I put the picture in my original post. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Bex.1233 sort out C1 as I said then run through the gap under the chip with a piece of copper linked to the ground net.

Answer (score 6):

The copper pour has a minimum width and a minimum clearance that must be met if it pour is to extend into an area. These settings can be changed in the pour's properties.

You could just draw those traces if you want to maintain larger clearances.

Comment: Don't think it is the clearances.  Even resistors with one end in the ground plane are affected.

Comment: Take that back.  Not all of them are affected. Bit even so, one pin on the chip is affected and it ought to have clearance.

Comment: @JRE The pins you're pointing at ARE connected to the ground plane, and are not the problem. The airwires are simply saying that the IC pins should be connected to the ground pads, and it just so happens the closest ground pads to the affected pins are the ones shown as needing connections. It's not saying pin 6 of the IC isn't connected to ground, it's saying that pin 6 of the IC should also be connected to pins 9 and 11